# Geometrically ruled surface, sections and intersection numbers.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, surfaces, schemes, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Consider a geometrically ruled surface $\pi: S\longrightarrow C$ where both $S$ and $C$ are projective, non-singular and complex ($C$ is obviously a curve). By using Tsen theorem one can show that there exists a section $\sigma:C\longrightarrow S$ such that $\pi\circ\sigma=id_C$.

Now, for every fiber  $F$ of $\pi$, it is clear that $\sigma(C)\cap F$ is a single point.

> But why $F.\sigma(C)=1$?

I mean, a fibre $F\cong\mathbb P^1$
 and $\sigma(C)$ could have the same tangent line on the intersection point.

(This ''fact'' is assumed as true without any explaination in Hartshorne book in the proof of the proposition $V.2.2$)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, a section cannot be tangent to a fibre at any point. $\pi \circ \sigma = \operatorname{id}$ implies that at any point $p = \sigma(q)$ in the image $\Gamma$ of the section, $(d_p \pi)_{|T_p \Gamma}$ must be an isomorphism onto $T_q C$.

On the other hand, $(d_p \pi)_{|T_p F} =0$ because $\pi$ is constant along $F$.

So if $\Gamma$ and $F$ share a tangent vector at $p$, then $(d_p \pi)_{|T_p \Gamma}$ is not injective, a contradiction.